# Unix , Delete first column using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file named test.txt which has the following content
`123,2,1`
I want to print the contents of the file without "123," 
I used the following
`awk -F, '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))} text.txt'`

It doesn't work properly tho, it prints `23,2,1` 
But when I run it for this text '123,5,1' , it works without a problem (it prints `5,1`)

Comment: simple `awk -F, '{print $2}' file` will does the job for you.

Comment: I want to print all columns , it just happened here I have only 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2- file
```

`-d,` uses `,` as delimiter, and `-f2-` prints fields 2 to last.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub()` function and remove the first field regardless of what it is.

```
$ echo '123,2,1' | awk '{sub(/[^,]+,/,"")}1' 
2,1
```

```
$ echo '23,2,1' | awk '{sub(/[^,]+,/,"")}1'
2,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk`

```
echo '123,2,1' | awk -F, '{$1="";sub(/,/,"")}1' OFS=,
2,1
```

Removes the first field, then the separator.